# Grabbing _seems_ to extrude rather than the expected movement?

Tags: transforms, extrude

First off, I know I've clearly got something wrong here and I'm interested in how I can diagnose the underlying issue.

I've got two low-poly car models here, with one of them if I select the six faces, that make up the back of the car, then `g` and `y` and pull backward - I get a result that sort of looks like extrusion:

[image: extrusion vs movement]

I looked carefully at my model to see if I had unexpected duplicated edges or issues like that. But I couldn't find any problems (which may just mean I didn't know how to look properly).

So I redid my model from scratch and with the newer model (on the left), if I select the same faces and do that same thing I pull the vertices that are shared with the middle of the car along too, as I expected.

I thought I constructed things identically for both models. So clearly I made a mistake somewhere so what was it? But I'm actually more interested in how I could have diagnosed the issue - I tried looking at the mesh in various different ways to see if I could spot something odd but was unsuccessful.

[image]

Comment: There only seem to be 2 faces that make up the part of the back of the car that you wanted to extend. Which six faces did you select?

Comment: On the right-hand model, I selected two faces each on the top, back and bottom and one on the left and right side (these are the faces you see selected in orange in my screenshot). I then pressed `g` and `y` and pulled backward but ended up with four new faces (the faces you see immediately behind the orange selected area) rather than pulling the bottom edges of the rear windscreen with me (at happens if I do the same with the left-hand model).

Comment: To be honest the only way I can see that could have happened is if you'd hit 'E' (Extrude) instead of 'G' by mistake!

Comment: And as @RichSedman suggests below it looks as if you've done exactly that at some stage! In Vertex mode, select all (A) on your bad object then M > Merge by Distance and watch the bottom status bar. You'll see that 33 vertices have been merged which is almost certainly what caused your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’ve pressed <kbd>E</kbd> and then <kbd>Escape</kbd> (or cancel button on the mouse) to cancel then you’ll have created invisible additional geometry; you’ve effectively extruded but left the vertices exactly where these where.

You won’t see any difference but if you later select and move them then it will look as if it’s extruding.

Simplest solution is to select all vertices and Merge By Distance’ to automatically merge any such duplicates.